# Getting Hashed Webpack Bundles Working in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, angular

In .NET Core, referred webpack bundles using `asp-src-include`. obviously main.js something like main.{hash}.js.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" asp-src-include="~/main*.js"></script>
```

Worked fine in .NET Core. But in .Net framework 4.5, obviously I can't able to use`asp-src-include`. So how to overcome this. `src` attribute not working like `asp-src-include`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/main*.js")"></script> //this is not working
```

Comment: would it help if the files are generated without hash, in that way you can simply include main.js without  wildcard

Comment: No I need hash to solve the cache issue in production.

Comment: What is your Angular version? Do you use Angular CLI?

Comment: @ArunKumar Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this in the BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AngularMain").IncludeDirectory(
                 "~/Scripts/dist/","main.*"))
```

Refer them in you layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AngularMain")
```

you can find more info in this link [Bundling and Minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)
I hope this might help